# How to import Onenote 2007 notebooks into onenote 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013, microsoft-onenote-2007

I recently installed the Onenote 2013 free edition on Win7 (32bit) edition.

While I can open, view and then convert `Unfiled Notes.one (2007)` into ON2013 since it's one single file (*.one) however 2007 notebook(s) is stored as a folder (on disk) with same name as the notebook and sections within that notebook as `.one` file within that folder(on disk).

For e.g If I create a Notebook in onenote 2007 and name it as *Travel* and create 2 sections within that notebook named *Planning* and *Trips_15* resp. Onenote 2007 will store the entire notebook as a folder named "Travel" and 2 *.one files within that folder named `Planning.one` & `Trips_15.one` resp.

Though I can open and view individual sections (*.one files) within 2013 but how to open the entire 2007 notebook with all its sections in Onenote 2013.

thanks
dkj

Answer (score 0):

If you double click an .one file within the notebook it will open in 2013 without issue and will load the notebook (we did this in the office as we switched from one version to the other). Also, once the notebook is open, if you go to its properties (right-click the notebook) you will have the option to convert it to 2013 (this allows you to use some newer features but don't if there are still users accessing the notebook with an earlier version.